# How to maintain project tree state (collapsed and/or expanded items) after closing and reopening the IDE?

Tags: rider

Every time I run Rider it shows the project tree completely collapsed or closed. I would like to keep the state of each node/item just as it was when I closed the IDE, similar to what happens in Visual Studio.
Is there any setting that allows this? I searched, but found nothing.

This is how Rider shows the "Solution" window every time I open it:

[image: This is how Rider shows the "Solution" window every time I open it.]

And that's how I want it:

[image: And that's how I want it:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to track the next issue in the JetBrains open issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-5094